# How to get the Entity name and type from DataGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, mvvm

This seems like it should be straight forward, but I can't seem to get the Models `Entities` type and name?

I can get the `class` name/type, but not the properties inside the `class` which I am accessing while editing the `DataGrid`.

This is the event in which I am trying to get the values:

```
protected void OnDataGrid_CellEditEnding(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.EditAction == DataGridEditAction.Commit)
        {
            var userControl = FindVisualParent<UserView>(sender as UIElement);
            var rowType = e.Row.Item.GetType(); //This gets the class type
               //trying to get name and type of entity here
            var name  = e.Row.Item. ??????
            var type = e.Row.Item.GetType(). ??????
        }            
    }
```

And this is the `Model`, I am using code first `EntityFrameWork`

```
public partial class Bank
{
    public System.Guid Id { get; set; } // ID (Primary key)
    public string Section { get; set; } // Section (length: 50)
    public string Name { get; set; } // Name (length: 50)

    public Bank()
    {
        InitializePartial();
    }

    partial void InitializePartial();
}
```

To try to make things a little more clearer, I am trying to get the `Property` name and type of of the `Property` named `Section` in the above class. How do I do this from the `OnDataGrid_CellEditEnding` event?

Comment: Cast it to your Bank class. `Bank iAmOfTypeBank = (Bank)e.Row.Item;`

Comment: When you are using MVVM why you are a `CellEditEndingEvent` instead doing it in your viewmodel? Another question: why binding a model instead of a viewmodel to your view?

Comment: @MightyBadaboom, it is bound to a wrapper class with the same properties, I figured posting everything would confuse things, but those are the property names and types I am trying to get. And your other question, I am using a property changed event in my view model, but when adding a new row to a datagrid, the empty row is not part of the bound collection, so I needed another way to be able to add new data to the collection.

Comment: @KyloRen Ok. The main problem is adding a new entry in your collection?

Comment: @MightyBadaboom, yes, that is the main issue to begin with. But, I do have this working, I just wanted to define some logic when a certain property was edited in the grid. What I did was create a generic Datagrid event which I can use for any Datagrid in the app.

Comment: @RandRandom, that seems to just give me a list of all the properties in the `Bank` class, not the single property being edited???

Comment: @KyloRen When you have a collection which is bound to a `DataGrid` and you add an entry in the `DataGrid` via view this item will be added in the collection as well but it need's an parameterless constructor. Isn't this working for you?

Comment: @MightyBadaboom, No the `propertyChanged_Event` is not fired when the empty row is edited, but it works fine on existing data. But, my `Wrapper` class does not have a `parameterless constructor`

Comment: @MightyBadaboom, OK, I can get the property name with an extension method in the `Base Wrapper`. Thanks for the help, this is solved.